# Theory of Object Oriented databases

Tags: ruby, database, oop, discrete-mathematics, object-oriented-database

Please recommend some material about implementing Object-Oriented Databases for dynamic languages (interested in Ruby).

I realise that OODBs do not have a good mathematical foundation, but still the information I could find is absolutely insufficient for me to start working on a new OODB.

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the motiv for your interest? Academic project or do you think it can have some commercial value? Thx.

Comment: The main motive is pain using existing databases + interest. The possibility of starting the real work on OODB is pretty low, but if I will - it will be Open Source one. No commercial targets set. But it would be good if it will have commercial value :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Won Kim's "Introduction to Object-Oriented Databases"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262512165). It's considered an authoritative source on the matter.

EDIT: An alternative reference is ["Object-Relational Database Development" by Paul Brown](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130194603). It takes an object/relational approach, which may be interesting given the prevalence of relational technologies these days.

Comment: Come on... Published in 1990. Too much water has gone for the last 20 years.

Comment: @Dmytrii: I invite you to provide some links to that "water". You need to take into account that OO databases is not a hot topic anymore.

Comment: Are you saying that OODBMSs have not evolved for the last 20 years? I refuse to believe it with the speed of IT evolution...

Comment: @Dmytrii: There have been advances, but not breakthroughs as far as I understand. You need to take into account that most of the stuff about OODBMSs that theorists proposed in the 1980s and 1990s could not be successfully imlpemented then because the thechnology wasn't good enough (e.g. object-level locking and access control granularity). Today, many of those ideas are viable. But, in any case, what you believe is up to you. :-)

Comment: I see your point and understand what you mean. Probably I was too optimistic in my question and intentions. Maybe you have other sources of OODB theory as well?

Comment: @Dmytrii: Editing my answer to provide an additional reference.

Answer (score 2):

There are several for pay papers:

[An implementation of a multimedia object-oriented database management system](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=494167)

[An object-oriented database system Jasmine: implementation, application, and extension](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=494167)

[The Design and Implementation of an Object Oriented Database Management System-OMNIX](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/TOOLS.1999.796515)

Then there's also the website odbms.org, which has resources online:

http://www.odbms.org/downloads.aspx

Last but not least I'd probably try to search for whitepapers or tech docs for a popular ODBMS like Caché.

Comment: Some commas in between the links might help.